# Change values from textbox at the touch of a button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

By clicking on the Ok button, the length and width should change, help to figure out how to write a function for the Click_Ok button.
When I choose View1, the textbox automatically displays information about this View1. I need if I want to change the value by typing a new one in the textbox by pressing the button to save it

ViewModel

```
class CameraViewModel : ViewModelBase
{   
    private ObservableCollection<CameraModel> camera = new ObservableCollection<CameraModel>
    {
        new CameraModel { View = "View1", Width = 100, Height = 100 }
    };

    public ObservableCollection<CameraModel> Camera
    {
        get { return camera; }
        set { camera = value; }
    }

    private CameraModel selectedCamera;    

    public CameraModel SelectedCamera
    {
        get { return selectedCamera; }
        set
        {
            selectedCamera = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCamera");
        }
    }

    public CameraViewModel()
    {         
        ClickOk = new BaseCommand(() => Click_Ok());
    }

    public ICommand ClickOk { get; set; }      

    private void Click_Ok()
    {

    }
}
```

View

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtWidth" Width="150" Height="30" Text="{Binding SelectedCamera.Width, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="txtHeight" Width="150" Height="30" Text="{Binding SelectedCamera.Height, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>

<Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Ok" Margin="10 10 10 10" Height="30" Width="75" Command="{Binding ClickOk}"/>
```

Model

```
class CameraModel
    {
        public string View { get; set; }        
        public int Width { get; set; } 
        public int Height { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Why did you put `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` on the Bindings? It will break the bindings. It's usually not a good idea to add stuff at random without looking it up. You'll break things. If you want the UI to update when SelectedCamera.Width changes, you'll need to raise a `PropertyChanged` event when it changes. The setter of `SelectedCamera` does not know that you called the getter, and then updated a property on the object the getter returned. Instead, `CameraModel` should be a viewmodel: It should inherit from ViewModelBase and the properties should raise PropertyChanged.

Comment: ...but once you've done that, `Click_Ok()` can just set the value of `SelectedCamera.Width`, or any other properly defined and bound viewmodel property, and the UI will reflect the change.

Comment: private int width;

        public int Width
        {
            get { return width; }
            set
            {
                width = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCamera");                
            }
        }
like that, do I understand correctly? @EdPlunkett

Comment: Yes, just like the other one. One thing I’d suggest is name the private fields with leading underscores so you can’t accidentally mistype Width as width and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private int _width;
        public int Width
        {
            get { return _width; }
            set
            {
                _width = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCamera");                
            }
        }

        private int _height;
        public int Height
        {
            get { return _height; }
            set
            {
                _height = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCamera");
            }
        }

<TextBox x:Name="txtWidth" Width="150" Height="30" Text="{Binding SelectedCamera.Width, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="txtHeight" Width="150" Height="30" Text="{Binding SelectedCamera.Height, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
First you need to create an action button and then change "text" or "value" property of textBox inside.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       textbox.text="word";
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The WPF TextBox class has no property named `text`, and the viewmodel does not have, and should not have, any reference to any TextBox instance in any case.